# OWIN - Object reference not set to an instance of object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am using asp.net mvc 5 to develop a web application.But i got some error while  playing with the users account.I have Created a user account and i want to delete it but facing the following issue while doing it with ajax-jquery. 
I am trying to delete a user account using ajax request but it gives the error for null object reference as Owin Context is not initiated due to ajax call.

```
 public class AdmissionsController : Controller
 {
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AdmissionsController()
    {

    }

    public AdmissionsController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _signInManager = value;
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }




    //function to delete user account
    public async Task<object> DeleteUser(string id)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        var logins = user.Logins;
        var rolesForUser = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(id);

        using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            foreach (var login in logins.ToList())
            {
                await _userManager.RemoveLoginAsync(login.UserId, new UserLoginInfo(login.LoginProvider, login.ProviderKey));
            }

            if (rolesForUser.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in rolesForUser.ToList())
                {
                    // item should be the name of the role
                    var result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user.Id, item);
                }
            }

            await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            transaction.Commit();
        }

        return new{success=true};

    }



}
```

And my ajax call as follow :

```
        var userid = $(this).attr("data-StudentId");
        var success = false;




        $.ajax({
            method: "Get",
            url: "/Area/Admissions/DeleteUser",
            data: { "id": userid },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.Success == true) {
                    success = true;

                }
                else if (response.Success == false) {
                       //window.location.reload();
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                notificationMSG("fa fa-thumbs-up", "error", "Error", response.message);
            }

        });
```

How can i resolve this issue???
I am getting the error at the following line:

```
  var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a wild guess, but it seems to me that you do not instantiate `_userManager`. You have a corresponding property where this creation takes place. However, in the line with error you use private field. Try to use the property:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
```

This will call the getter where you get this manager from the owin context.